# python+arduino: trying to simulate a mouse click, but it autoclicks instead

Tags: python, arduino, mouse

im trying to program something that will mirror a left click function of a regular mouse, instead what its doing is, clicking 35 a second when i hold the button down instead of acting like a press and hold.
This is the python part and its reading in 3 numbers from the arduino and Z represents the on or off state of the click.

```
import serial
import pydirectinput
import time
import pyautogui
try:
    arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 115200, timeout=.1)
except serial.SerialException as e:
    print(f"Error opening serial port: {e}")
    exit()

pydirectinput.PAUSE=0
pyautogui.PAUSE=0
pyautogui.FAILSAFE=False
keys_down = {}  # list of currently pressed keys


def key_down(key):
    keys_down[key] = True
    pydirectinput.keyDown(key)


def key_up(key):
    if key in keys_down:
        del keys_down[key]
        pydirectinput.keyUp(key)


def handle_joystick_as_arrow_keys(x, y, z):
    if x == 0:
        pyautogui.moveRel(0, -10)#drag 10 pixels up
    elif x == 2:
        pyautogui.moveRel(0, 10)#drag 10 pixels down

    if y == 2:
        pyautogui.moveRel(-10, 0)
    elif y == 0:
        pyautogui.moveRel(10, 0)
    if z == 1:
        pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
    else:
        pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')

        
try:
    while True:
        raw_data = arduino.readline()
        data = str(raw_data.decode('utf-8'))
        if data.startswith("S"):
            x_direction = int(data[1])
            y_direction = int(data[3])
            joystick_button = int(data[5])

            handle_joystick_as_arrow_keys(x_direction, y_direction, joystick_button)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Script terminated by user.")

finally:
    arduino.close()
```

This is the arduino part.

```
const int JoyStick_pin = 8; //plug Joystick 'Button' into pin 8
const int X_pin = A0;       //plug joystick X direction into pin A0
const int Y_pin = A1;       //plug joystick Y direction into pin A1
int xc;
int yc;
int JSButton;
int prevButtonState = HIGH; //

void setup() {
    pinMode(JoyStick_pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  int x = analogRead(X_pin) - 517;  //read x direction value and -517 to bring back to around 0
  int y = analogRead(Y_pin) - 512;  //read y direction value and -512 to bring back to around 0

  if (x <-10) {         //joystick has off set of +/-8 so this negates that
    xc = 0;             //turn analogue value into integer. 0, 1 or 2 depending on state
  } else if (x >10) {   
    xc = 2;
  } else {
    xc = 1;
  }

  if (y <-10) {
    yc = 0;
  } else if (y >10) {
    yc = 2;
  } else {
    yc = 1;
  }

  int buttonStates = 0;   //set starting value of Joystick button

  buttonStates |= ((digitalRead(JoyStick_pin) == LOW) ? 1 : 0) << 0;
 
  Serial.print("S");  //start printing the data, format is Sxc,yc,buttonStates > S1,1,0
  Serial.print(xc);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(yc);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println((buttonStates));

  delay(40);

}
```

originally i was using pyautogui.click() but it was doing the same thing, so i thought if i did a if z=1 then left click down, if 0 then up, that will fix it but it doesnt seem to change anything.

Comment: maybe you should use some variable to remember that it was already clicked and reset this variable when you unpress button?

Comment: I think your code repeat the same function many times and using only `z == 1` is useless. You have to remember also previous state and when previous was `0` and current is `1` then `press`, when previous was `1` and current is `0` then `unpress` and when previous was `1` and current is `1` then do nothing, and the same when previous was `0` and current is `0` then do nothing.

Comment: i tested the changes you suggested and it works kind of? whenever I press a button using the joystick it'll click once, but if I try to for example move my google chrome tab around, it'll revert to clicking really fast (so it maximizes the tab) which is confusing, so I used a cps test to see how fast I'm clicking but its only clicking once per tap. do you have any idea why?

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see what you have in variables when you click. Maybe when you move then it reset `z` and this makes problem. Did you test if `tab` has this problem with real mouse? Maybe this is natural behavior when you move mouse

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but I think so you should remember `previous z` and:

- `press` when previous was `0` and current is `1`
- `unpress` when previous was `1` and current is `0`
- in other situations do nothing

It could be like

```
previous_z = 0   # global variable to remember previous value

def handle_joystick_as_arrow_keys(x, y, z):
    global previous_z   # inform function that you will assign new value to global variable

    if previous_z == 0 and z == 1:
        pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
    elif previous_z == 1 and z == 0:
        pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
    #else:
    #  do nothing

    previous_z = z
```